# Is there a Bitcoin wallet that has French language support?

Tags: wallet, client, buy-bitcoins

Which Bitcoin app has a language option that can be changed from English to French?

I have tried few applications but they seem to be no language option.

Comment: You can use Google translator add on. Read more here - https://support.google.com/translate/answer/2534601?hl=en

Comment: If you use Firefox use this one - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google-translator-for-firefox/

Answer (score 2):

The main bitcoin core client can be run in a foreign language.

Close the Bitcoin client and add this line:

```
lang=fr
```

On a line by itself to the end of the file:

C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin\bitcoin.conf

(Replace "YourUserName" with your windows user name.)

Now restart the Bitcoin client.  Done!